# How would I loop this code to include all the columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, append

below is how the data is structured

I'm sure this is simple, but as a newbie to python, I'm having trouble figuring out how to iterate over variables.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 35 entries, 2021-02-25 to 2021-04-15
Data columns (total 11 columns):
dtypes: float64(11)
```

suppose I wanted to loop the code below so it performs the function on all the columns and outputs df. How would I do that?

```
n_days = 6
n=len(prices)- n_days
dnum = np.arange(1,n, 1).tolist()

a_list = []
b_list = []
c_list = []
d_list = []
e_list = []
f_list = []


for x in dnum:
  s = x 
  i = n_days+x
  new_prices = prices[s:i]
  
  returns = new_prices['fngu'].to_returns().dropna()
  sharp_1 = returns.calc_sharpe_ratio(nperiods=365)
  
  returns = new_prices['soxl'].to_returns().dropna()
  sharp_2 = returns.calc_sharpe_ratio(nperiods=365)
  
  returns = new_prices['spxl'].to_returns().dropna()
  sharp_3 = returns.calc_sharpe_ratio(nperiods=365)
  
  returns = new_prices['fas'].to_returns().dropna()
  sharp_4 = returns.calc_sharpe_ratio(nperiods=365)
  
  returns = new_prices['utsl'].to_returns().dropna()
  sharp_5 = returns.calc_sharpe_ratio(nperiods=365)

  date = prices.index[i]
  
  a_list.append(date)
  b_list.append(sharp_1)
  c_list.append(sharp_2)
  d_list.append(sharp_3)
  e_list.append(sharp_4)
  f_list.append(sharp_5)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': a_list, 'fngu': b_list, 'soxl': c_list, 'spxl': d_list, 'fas': e_list, 'utsl': f_list})
del a_list, b_list, c_list, d_list, e_list, f_list
```

I tried using concat and iteritems function but I am too much of a noob for that

EDIT::
I sort of came up with solution from other posts,

```
r_list = []

for x in dnum:
  s = x 
  i = n_days+x
  new_prices = prices[s:i]
  returns = new_prices.to_returns().dropna()
  sharp = returns.calc_sharpe_ratio(nperiods=365)
  sharp['Date'] = prices.index[i]
  s = pd.DataFrame(sharp)
  s= s.transpose()
  r_list.append(s)
df = pd.concat(r_list)
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

This works for what I need but I would like to learn the most efficient way to do this type of loop or something else.

Comment: You should not normally use for loops on numpy/pandas dataframe or matrixes. It's not efficient. These libraries are designed so the user can perform vectorized operations on the data which will be way faster than looping. Also how does `prices` dataframe look like?

Comment: @PooyaKamranjam its just column of dates and prices, the goal is to calculate rolling sharpe ratio `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 70 entries, 2021-01-06 to 2021-04-16
Data columns (total 10 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   googl   70 non-null     float64
 1   aapl    70 non-null     float64
 2   fb      70 non-null     float64
 3   nvda    70 non-null     float64
 4   amzn    70 non-null     float64....`